# My server doesn't support resume or multi - threading,

Tags: multithreading, server, resume

Having WordPress eCommerce store and just developed Android and iPhone application for the same store.

The product is MP3 file's, while downloading if we press pause button then again resume, it says your server doesn't support resume and multi - threading feature.

Can you please help me what shall I do to enable the resume feature. Is it the server side configuration?

Look forward to hearing from you. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In one off our application we resolve this kind of issue for (Android/iPhone) by doing necessary change in WordPress Back-end Admin.

Steps:-

- After loging onto WordPress Back-end Admin navigate to
- WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Downloadable Products
- For Option "File Download Method" select "Redirect Only" as option